Handling Alert/Pop-up Selenium Java. Simple Google example code
I cannot seem to find a way to get these alerts on my work fixed using my old code. So if anyone could help with this simple code it would be great so I can move it to mine.
When the automation google launches it had an alert which can be rejected or accepted but every code I use does not work.
public class GoogleSearchSteps {

    WebDriver driver = null;

    @Given("browser is open")
    public void browser_is_open() {
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("Project Path is "+projectPath);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath+ "/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }


    @And("user is on the google search page")
    public void user_is_on_the_google_search_page() {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");

    }
    @When("user enters text in google search bar")
    public void user_enters_text_in_google_search_bar() {
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("arsenal");

    }
    @And("hit enter")
    public void hit_enter() {
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    }
    @Then("user is navigated to the search results page")
    public void user_is_navigated_to_the_search_results_page() {
        driver.getPageSource().contains("Arsenal");
        driver.quit();

    }
}


Use the code below to handle the accept/reject cookies pop-up. Below line of code will click on Accept all button.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Accept all']")).click();

You can use it after launching the google page.
